# Taking the several ending Bash arguments as commands in a for loop

Tags: bash

I was just messing around trying to make a little simpler, or at least custom, for loop script named `loop`. I would like it to be in the syntax...

```
loop <start> <end> <command>
```

I was doing it like this but I cannot figure out how to pass in the command argument into the loop. The only ways I know how to do this is `bash -c` which will take the first argument after options as a command and $@ which will take everything. I need it to ignore the first two arguments. Everything after those two will be executed in the loop.

So even something like this would work.

```
loop 1 1000 for ((i=1; i<1000; i++)); do touch some_dir; done
```

This is what I have which works fine so far, obviously without the command.

```
for ((i=$1; i<$2; i++)); do echo "yaaaa!"; done;
```

Comment: `start=$1; end=$2; shift 2; cmd="$@"` or something similar will get your close. use `set -vx` to see what is happening with variables inside your tests. Good luck.

Comment: Without quoting the arguments to the `loop` script this isn't really going to be possible and at that point you are talking about using `eval` on the given argument string I believe.

Comment: Yea eval might work good idea

Comment: The bash syntax for "all the arguments starting with number `i`" is `"${@:i}"`. Here, `i` can be any [arithmetic expression][1], not just an integer (although integers are fine). However, as @EtanReisner points out, you'll need to delay evaluation of the command line arguments if you want to be able to use `$i` (or some other loop variable) in the supplied command line, and that is notoriously difficult because of the complications with quoting quotes and other bash syntax.

Comment: What @rici was saying (and what I was hinting at) is that this is a bad idea and not likely to work at all well. Better would be to have `loop` just take a script directly (or stdin if necessary) and loop over running that (with an exported loop control variable if necessary). And even that is not really worth the effort to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this?

```
function loop
{
    local START=$1
    local END=$2
    shift 2
    for LOOP in `seq $START $END`
    do
        "$@"
    done
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
loop 1 10 echo "yaaaa!"
```